# How to get past `import gv` in python-graph?

Tags: python, macos, python-import

I would like to run the [python/graphviz example code](https://code.google.com/p/python-graph/wiki/Example).

First I install python-graph

```
sudo easy_install python-graph-core
sudo easy_install python-graph-dot
```

then I install graphviz

```
sudo port install graphviz
```

Since the writer of the example code seems to be on linux and I'm on OS X, I replace

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/graphviz/python/')
sys.path.append('/usr/lib64/graphviz/python/')
import gv
```

with

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')
sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages')
sys.path.append('/opt/local/lib/graphviz')
import gv
```

I insert the former because easy_install has reported that both python-graph modules have been installed in

```
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/python_graph_core-1.8.2-py2.7.egg
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyparsing-2.0.3-py2.7.egg
```

I insert the latter because that's where I see MacPorts has installed graphviz.

Still, trying to run the example code stops with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./graph-example.py", line 12, in <module>
    import gv
ImportError: No module named gv
```

How do I get past `import gv`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running:

```
sudo pip install pygraphviz
```

Then you should just be able to use:

```
import gv
```

in python.

Comment: I tried 1- without any sys.path.append.. 2- (since I see that pygraphviz went into /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pygraphviz) using sys.path.append('/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages') and 3- by first adding export PYTHONPATH=/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages:.:$PYTHONPATH in my .bash_profile (and starting a new Terminal). None worked.

Comment: What happens when you did the pip install? If you type `pip list | grep gv` do you get any results?

Comment: Just to make sure we're talking about the same pip, `which pip` gives me `usr/local/bin/pip` . Now to `pip list | grep gv`. That gives me nothing. But graphviz is there all right. If I try `pip list | grep graph`, I get altgraph, modulegraph, pygraphviz, python-graph-core, and python-graph-dot.